# How do I add new items to a cart and iterate through them to display using php?

Tags: php, loops, session, shopping-cart

I am trying to pass data from a product page into a shopping cart page using an array.  There are multiple attributes that the viewcart.php will receive from the previous page (price, link, title, and retailer). I’d like to save them all using an array.  For each additional item a customer adds to the shopping cart, I’m trying to get a counter variable ($i) to increment an array $_SESSION[‘cart’][$i][‘attribute’].  How do I do this?

I’m not sure this is the right way to add new products to the cart.  In the end, I’d like a way to be able to display all the products in the cart using a for loop.  This is the start I have so far on the shopping cart script:

```
<?php

  // The shopping cart needs sessions, so start one
  session_start();

  @$link = $_GET['link'];
$price = $_GET['price'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
$retailer = $_GET['retailer'];


  if($link) {
    //new item selected
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
      $_SESSION['items'] = 0;
      $_SESSION['total_price'] ='0.00';
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$link])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'][$link]++;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['cart'][$link] = 1;
    }


  }

  if(($_SESSION['cart']) && (array_count_values($_SESSION['cart']))) {
    echo " in your cart and we're working to display them";
  } 
  else {
    echo "<p>There are no items in your cart</p><hr/>";
  }

?>
```

This is the for loop that I’m thinking I could use.  I’m looking for some way to display all the items in the array.

```
for ($x=0; $x<=$i; $i++)
  {
  echo "The price is " . $_SESSION['cart'][$x][price] . "  Retailer is " . $_SESSION['cart'][$x]    [retailer] . "<br>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by creating a temp_cart table in your database.. in which you should store the items that user adds to their cart.. Then on checkout page.. you can simply display them using select query. In that way.. it will be easier for you to allow the user to edit their cart on viewcart.php page.

Answer (score 0):

You could:
Have another session variable with the counter and increment it each add?

Or

```
$i= Count($_SESSION['cart'])+1;
```

Or

Don't specify an index at all:

$tmp["cart"]["retailer"] = "123";
Etc etc..

$_SESSION['cart'][] = $tmp["cart"];

I would be storing the products into a database if I was you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the way you are doing this. Session management is very simple for shopping carts. Keep your session as lite as possible. Storing price in the session is very bad way, as it can be easily manipulated.

Here is a simple example of what you can use.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['items'][$_GET['item_id']])) {
    $_SESSION['items'][$_GET['item_id']]++; //add one to the total count
} else {
    $_SESSION['items'][$_GET['item_id']] = 1; //If added for the first time
}
```

Now process it

```
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $id => $count) {
     echo $id; // product id
     echo $count; // product count
}
```

---

<sup>**P.S: Remember to sanitize the input. I have omitted that**</sup>